# Jquery - Can a draggable be set to revert = true from revert = invalid

Tags: jquery, draggable, helper, revert

Is it possible to set a draggables revert value to "true" when it was originally set to "invalid"?  I am trying to revert the draggable in the drop event of the droppable, but the revert doesnt happen.

```
var dragOpts = {
                /* appendTo: "body", */
                zIndex: 1000,
                cursor: "move",
                revert: "invalid",
                opacity: 0.45,
                helper: myHelper,
};

$(".appointment").draggable(dragOpts);

    function myHelper(event, ui) {

    var height = $(this).children().not('.travel-element').css("height");
    var cloneClass = $(this).children().not('.travel-element').attr("class");

     return $("<div id='helper' class='" + cloneClass + "' style='height:" + height            + "'>Moving</div>");
    }



drop: function (e, ui) {
        $(".appointment").draggable({revert:true});

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.draggable('option', 'revert', true)`

Fyi, this is the regular way to change options for *any* jQuery UI widget and also explained in the docs.